# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget while overlaying on Google map on Android ?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes, overlay, out-of-memory

What I want to do: I want to setup some routes overlay on google map in android !

What I have done so far: I have parsed the file (geo points) and have them ! I am using asynctask. My overlay class has a custom draw method. I have used destroyDrawingCache () in my draw function.

Problems I faced: While running the app, it gets size exceed error. I can see that the heap size is about 12mb at the time of the error.

Can anyone please help me out ? Thanks!

```
/////////////////////////////Error Message/////////////////////////////

10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.generateNewTileImage(StreetViewRenderer.java:120)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.renderTile(StreetViewRenderer.java:88)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.android.maps.AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.renderTile(AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.java:62)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-11 19:23:02.059: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(483):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

the draw code :

```
   public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){

     BusLoc.myMapView.destroyDrawingCache ();
     super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

        Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

        //ah1[0][0]=35767138;
        //ah1[0][1]=-78695548;
        //ah1[1][0]=35787497;
        //ah1[1][1]=-78667474;



        Log.d("MyOverlay","OnDraw");

        int in=0;
        for(in=0;in<ind-1;in++)
        {
         if (ah1[in][0] ==0 ||(ah1[in+1][0]==0)) break;
         if((ah1[in][0] !=0) &&(ah1[in+1][0]!=0))
         {
          GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint((int)(ah1[in][0]*1e6),(int)(ah1[in][1]*1e6));
          GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint((int)(ah1[in+1][0]*1e6),(int)(ah1[in+1][1]*1e6));



          Point p1 = new Point();
          Point p2 = new Point();

          Path path = new Path();

          Projection projection = BusLoc.myMapView.getProjection();
    projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
          projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);

          path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
          path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);

          canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);

          Log.d("MyOverlay","drawn: "+gP1.toString()+":"+gP2.toString());
         }
        }
        BusLoc.myMapView.destroyDrawingCache ();
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do too much work in memory.  How many points do you have?  You need to find a way to not store everything in memory at the same time.

Comment: Well, there are lots of points ..there are like a hundred segment in the route and for each segment there are probably 50 points ! Is there a way out ? Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: However, even with only 2 points, I am facing the same problem :(

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using to draw?

Comment: ok, am attaching to the ques.

Comment: i dont get it..even the heap is now showing 23.8% usage..why do I get this funny error ??? :(

Comment: Do you mean to multiply by 1e6? In your example the values are already 3.5e7...

Comment: Oh... Didn't realise how old this was.